# Pushing files on one git-branch

Tags: git, push, commit

I have a website on a server and I want to begin sharing my work and so I am working with git. I am very new to it.

So on the remote server, I made a "git init" and a git commit to move all the work on the .git directory (always on the remote server).

Then I made a git clone (with an ssh connection) on my local server. And then I changed some files and committed it (worked fine) and then pushed it, but here is the error message :

```
remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master
remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository
remote: error: is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent
remote: error: with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match
remote: error: the work tree to HEAD.
remote: error: 
remote: error: You can set 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to
remote: error: 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing into
remote: error: its current branch; however, this is not recommended unless you
remote: error: arranged to update its work tree to match what you pushed in some
remote: error: other way.
remote: error: 
remote: error: To squelch this message and still keep the default behaviour, set
remote: error: 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to 'refuse'.
To ssh://sameditr@ftp.sameditresfroid.fr/homez.501/sameditr/www/.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh:...'
```

Does anybody has an idea ?

Best,
Newben

Answer (score 1):

If you meant to create *central* repository on remote server, you should create *bare* repository:

```
git init --bare
```

You can configure current non-bare repository to accept updates (the error message is even telling you how), but much simpler way is to delete current repo on a remote server and create the new, bare one.

Here's a link to [detailed explanation of difference between bare and non-bare repos.](http://www.bitflop.com/document/111)

Comment: So you mean that I must delete the actual git repo on the server and on local and then create a new git repo ? Best,Newben

Comment: If that repo is new and you don't have any history of commits to lose, then yes, it's the best option.

Comment: Oh, in fact now I get an error message  "This operation must be run in a work tree" becaus I am trying a git add www ./.git. I don't understand anything of this mess ! Best , Newben

Answer (score 1):

I usually do the following:

on server, inside webapp directory

```
$ git init
$ git add *
$ git commit -a
```

to have at lease an Initial Commit

on dev computer, you may do:

```
$ git init
$ git remote add origin git+ssh://server/var/www/.git/
$ git branch --set-upstream master origin/master
$ git pull
```

edit files on dev

```
$ git push
```

Hope this helps!